# What will happen to water at $0^\circ$ Celsius kept in large evacuated chamber

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

Suppose some water is kept at $0^\circ$, in a glass (ideal container, if necessary). Now it is placed in a large evacuated chamber. **What will happen?**

I think some water will vaporize, some will freeze and rest will remain liquid. But then I think how can water exist in liquid phase in such a high volume. Then I think I am confused, so I must ask it here.

Comment: You're right that some will vaporize and the rest will remain as solid or liquid. This was actually how dry ice was originally made in 1835 (by vaporizing part of the liquid $\text{CO}_2$ to leave frozen solid remainder).

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus ".. remain as **solid or liquid**", aren't you sure. This is confusing me even more. You may be saying that the rest water will remain as either solid or liquid, but not both. Then, What are the conditions for it to remain as solid or as liquid?

Comment: It depends on how long you let it evaporate for. As long as there is still liquid water, the solid-liquid mix will be at approximately 0 Celcius (I say approximately because according to the Clausius-Clapeyron relation there will be a change in water freezing point upon pressure reduction, but due to the high bulk modulus of water, this effect is very small). So as long as you're applying vacuum and as long as liquid surface is exposed, liquid will evaporate and in the process generate more solid, until the surface becomes covered with solid or until the liquid runs out and it's all solid.

Comment: @AbhishekVerma I think that There will be only solid and gaseous state of water! To make-up some pressure, some part of ice will sublime to vapors and when the pressure is not enough to make ice sublime, the ice will remain and not water because ice exerts more volume than water so, **NO** water only ice and vapors.

Comment: This experiment has been performed, although with impure water...  http://www.howstuffworks.com/10-moments-space-bathrooms2.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the walls.  If they are truly insulated, no heat will flow in or out.  The water that freezes raises the temperature, while the water that evaporates lowers the temperature.  The [triple point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_%28molecule%29#Triple_point) of water is $0.01^\circ C, 611.73$ Pascals.  If the chamber is very large, relatively much of the water will evaporate and the temperature will be below the triple point.  You will form an ice/vapor equilibrium.  If the chamber is not much larger than the water volume, a little water will evaporate, more water will freeze, and you will be at the triple point. Since the volume of water and ice are not very different, you can calculate how much vapor is there from the total mass of water.  Then you can calculate the amount of ice to make the temperature right.  You won't be far wrong.  If you want, you can iterate looking at the change in the volume of water/ice.

Answer (score 1):

When one says the boiling point is x degrees at such a pressure, what it means is that it holds a partial vapour pressure up to this.  Heat is fed in to make water into steam, even at room temperature, but it's so slight you don't notice it in the speciic heat.

When you have a large volume, a large amount of water is turned into steam, until the correct vapour pressure is met.  For tiny volumes, the pressure can get high quickly, and water can be heated beyond 100 centigrade, right up to 373 c.

For a small amount of water at 32 Fahr, it will all vapourise if the pressure is less than the boiling pressure at 0c.